# Automatically include AMD deps in Typescript AMD module?

Tags: requirejs, typescript

Is there a way to import or annotate Typescript modules such that external AMD modules will automatically be included as dependencies when generating an AMD-compatible module?:

```
tsc --module AMD example.ts
```

I've tried to include both including a reference *.d.ts file, and exporting declare statements:

```
///<reference path='./lib/knockout-2.2.d.ts' />

export declare var $;
export declare var _;

export module example {
    export class Example {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

However the generated module does not include these:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    (function (example) {
        var Example = (function () {
            function Example() { }
            return Example;
        })();
        example.Example = Example;        
    })(exports.example || (exports.example = {}));
    var example = exports.example;
})
```

Would really like to avoid creating "fake" modules here.

It seems like a nice solution and usage would be to allow importing AMD modules directly:

```
var $ = import('jquery'); // This is a requirejs/AMD module, not a typescript file.
```

but I don't know how feasible that is.

Edit:

And I've also tried this approach mentioned here: [Import TypeScript module using only ambient definition for use in amd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013366/import-typescript-module-using-only-ambient-definition-for-use-in-amd)

```
import knockout = module("./lib/knockout-2.2.d.ts");
...
```

but get these compiler errors:

```
example.ts(1,32): The name '"./lib/knockout-2.2.d.ts"' does not exist in the current scope
example.ts(1,32): A module cannot be aliased to a non-module type
```

Comment: Did you find a good solution for this?

Comment: No - in my case I started realizing it was easier to concat my Typescript application to a single file (`tsc --out`) instead of worrying about AMD, since wasn't lazy-loading anything.

Comment: I just found /// <amd-dependency path="path/to/knockout/js" /> - but can first test it when i get home.

Comment: but i havent been able to solve it 100%, it adds knockout to the dependencies but not to the function parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the more recent versions of TypeScript the correct way to do this is...

## Example (happens to be jQuery)

Step 1: Download the definition file from NuGet (i.e. jquery.typescript)

Step 2: Here is the code (the reference comment isn't necessary in Visual Studio):

```
/// <reference path="scripts/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

import $ = require('jquery');

export module foo {
    var elem = $('#myid');
}
```

The resulting JavaScript:

```
define(["require", "exports", 'jquery'], function(require, exports, $) {
    (function (foo) {
        var elem = $('#myid');
    })(exports.foo || (exports.foo = {}));
    var foo = exports.foo;
});
```

## Knockout

Some people were having trouble with Knockout... The same technique works for Knockout...

```
/// <reference path="scripts/typings/knockout/knockout.d.ts" />

import ko = require('knockout');

export module foo {
    var obs = ko.observable('example');
}
```

The resulting JavaScript:

```
define(["require", "exports", 'knockout'], function(require, exports, ko) {
    (function (foo) {
        var n = ko.observable('example');
    })(exports.foo || (exports.foo = {}));
    var foo = exports.foo;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
declare module 'jquery' { export var n; };

import $ = module('jquery');

export module foo {
    var n = $.n;
}
```

Will result in a proper `define` call:

```
define(["require", "exports", 'jquery'], ...
```

Note that if you don't use an imported value (`$` in this example) in a *value* position (as opposed to only in type positions), the compiler will optimize away that dependency.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, will give it a shot.  While I know the JS module space is a bit of a mess with CommonJS, AMD, etc and not TypeScript's fault - it seems valuable to easily include external modules in TS without these workarounds.

Comment: cant get it to work for knockout. when import ko = module('knockout'), ko cant be used as ko.observable() after

Answer (score 0):

Ryan's answer worked except that the new declare hides the types referenced in the triple commented ".d.ts" file.

To overcome this, you may want to try to change the declare like this:

```
declare module 'knockout' { export = knockout; }
```

I did not test with knockout but the solution should work with that also.