# How to get knockout imported in typescript with requirejs

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, typescript

I have been playing around with typescript for a few hours now and havent figured out how i import knockout together with my modules?

Without typescript i would need it in my `define(["require", "exports", "knockout" ...],function(... , ko)`, but i havent managed to get the typescript to generate that.

I dont know what the difference is from jquery to knockout, $ works fine, but ko is undefined.

```
///<reference path="../knockoutd.d.ts" />
///<reference path="../jquery.d.ts" />
import dl = module("DataLayer");
import vm1 = module("AppBarViewModel");
import vm2 = module("Nav2ViewModelCommander");
import vm3 = module("IdentityViewModel");
export class AppViewModel {
...
}
```

results in :

```
    define(["require", "exports", "DataLayer", "AppBarViewModel", "Nav2ViewModelCommander",  "IdentityViewModel"], function(require, exports, __dl__, __vm1__, __vm2__, __vm3__) {
    var dl = __dl__;

    var vm1 = __vm1__;

    var vm2 = __vm2__;

    var vm3 = __vm3__;
```

## update

With `///<amd-dependency path="knockout" />`

```
define(["require", "exports", "DataLayer", "AppBarViewModel", "Nav2ViewModelCommander", "IdentityViewModel", "knockout"], function(require, exports, __dl__, __vm1__, __vm2__, __vm3__) {
    var dl = __dl__;

    var vm1 = __vm1__;

    var vm2 = __vm2__;

    var vm3 = __vm3__;
```

Comment: Is your `knockout.ts` file a TypeScript version of Knockout or a definition file of Knockout? You may need to share the Knockout file in order to get a correct answer.

Comment: sorry. that was me playing around to try getting it to work. Thats a definition file. knockout.d.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With latest typescript and type definition for knockout.d.ts

```
import ko = require('knockout')
```

works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

To make the compiler include AMD dependencies in your resulting JavaScript without importing them in your TypeScript, you can make use of this code:

```
/// <amd-dependency path="path/to/knockout/js" />
```

This feature is badly documented, but oh-so-useful.

Comment: Will try it out, and yes if this was more documented i would have saved some hours of frustration.

Comment: It worked somewhat. It adds knockout to the dependencies, but not the the function(.... , ko ).

Comment: you are compiling to AMD modules are you?

Comment: I am compiling to AMD modules yes.

Comment: Could you post the relevant part (the define function) of the result? You can use pastbin or a similar service for this.

Comment: I added it to the question. But it just includes the knockout to the depentencies. i have defined the path in the require config, such knockout : 'path/to/knockout'

Comment: Ah yes this will only include it as an AMD dependency without actually putting it in the function signature. I didn't know about that, I use this to include required files that don't need to be imported. For example when the included file will set some global variables. The ko you are referring to, is this an AMD version? Or will it set the global variable ko? In the latter this approach should work.

Comment: I assume that ko should set the global ko, but thats where it do fail. It says ko is undefined and i cant figure out why. Normaly if i include the knockout.js file i just use ko.methods.

Comment: i put minimal solution on github. Feel free to mess around with it. https://github.com/s093294/typescript-knockout and let me know if you can get it working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27899/discussion-between-anzeo-and-s093294)

Comment: ko undefines its global when it finds an AMD loader, hence it isn't around

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that KnockoutJS doesn't define `window.ko` in an AMD environment (i.e. when RequireJS is involved).  Therefore you either have to use `///<amd-dependency />` or use KnockoutJS as a proper module.

I have [drafted up an AMD version of **knockout.d.ts**](https://github.com/diachedelic/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/knockout) from DefinitelyTyped - it will allow you to use `import ko = module('knockout')`.  Make sure you obtain both **knockout.d.ts** and **knockout.amd.d.ts**.

Comment: The knockout.amd.d.ts is gone now right? I just started a new project wiht newest typescript version and having trouble again. import ko = module("knockout");

Comment: knockout.amd.d.ts is not needed. knockout is a named amd module and therefore the module is defined in knockout.d.ts. You can do import ko = require("knockout"); just fine with latest ts and type definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following:

```
import ko= module("knockout");
```

**Update**

*Case 1:*

This seems more plausible based on your error `module can not be aliased to a none module type` Your knockout.ts file does not contain a module definition. To import a file file with the module directive there should be a module defined in that file.

*Case 2*

In case this is not working it is most likely due to this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13013956/390330 You should give the path to knockout.d.ts file :

```
import ko= module("/path/to/knockout.d.ts");
```

However I think it should not be required since you are referencing a .ts file and not a .d.ts file :

```
///<reference path="knockout.ts" />
```

Comment: I get a "The name "knockout" do not exists in the current scope. a module can not be aliased to a none module type".